# How to install Xvfb without root access (tried with linuxbrew)

Tags: debian, headless, xvfb

I have **non-root** access to a headless Debian server that runs Jenkins. I want to build [Unity3D](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Unity3dBuilder+Plugin) on that Jenkins, which requires me to install [Xvfb](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin). Because it is a headless server, X11 is not installed, and because I don't have root access, I can't install software.

To get around this, I installed [Linuxbrew](http://linuxbrew.sh/), which is a Linux port of [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), which allows you to install software in your `$HOME` and which does not require root access, as suggested in [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/593057/223724).

However, when I do

```
brew search xvfb
```

then I don't get any results, which means no Xvfb in Linuxbrew. The search is case-insensitive.

What other options do I have to install Xvfb without having root access?

Comment: There is an option for headless Unity3D build: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUserBuildSettings-enableHeadlessMode.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option of using xvfb from python to achieve what you are planning, you could use another package manager that is an alternative to linuxbrew, called [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/).

Once installed you could search for xvfb package and install it locally for your convenience. The package for conda is called - `xvfbwrapper` but you can install [other](https://anaconda.org/search?q=xvfb) flavors of it too.

You can find more details about this package on github under the same name.

Comment: Unfortunately Python is not installed. Can Python be installed by a non-root user?

Comment: Yes. Again, use anaconda to install it. You can install multiple versions too. By creating separate environments you will not have them in conflict. Anaconda is rather well documented and is available on many platforms. Start with miniconda unless you are sure about full bundle of anaconda.